# Nifty Gui doesn't react to input

Tags: java, xml, user-interface, slick2d, nifty-gui

Good morning! 
I'm trying Nifty Gui with Slick2d. Everything works correct besides input polling by Nifty Gui. It doen't react at all! Here is part of my code:

Xml:

```
<nifty xmlns="http://nifty-gui.lessvoid.com/nifty-gui">
    <screen id="GamePlay" controller="GamePlayScreenController">
        <layer childLayout="vertical">
            <panel id="roomListPanel" width="100%" height="32px" 
            childLayout="absolute-inside" padding="5px">

                <control id="appendButton" name="button" label="Pause">
            <interact onClick="test()" />       
        </control>
            </panel>
        </layer>
    </screen>
</nifty>
```

Java:

```
class GamePlayScreenController implements ScreenController {
    public void bind(Nifty nifty, Screen screen) {
        System.out.println("Bind");
    }

    public void onEndScreen() {
        System.out.println("End");
    }

    public void onStartScreen() {
        System.out.println("Start");
    }

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}

... 

// In my state class:

this.nifty = new Nifty(new LwjglRenderDevice(), new NullSoundDevice(),       new LwjglInputSystem(), new TimeProvider());

this.nifty.loadStyleFile("nifty-default-styles.xml");
this.nifty.loadControlFile("nifty-default-controls.xml");
this.nifty.registerScreenController(new GamePlayScreenController());
this.nifty.fromXml("data/test.xml", "GamePlay");
this.nifty.gotoScreen("GamePlay");

...

this.nifty.update();

... 

SlickCallable.enterSafeBlock();
this.nifty.render(false);
SlickCallable.leaveSafeBlock();
```

I have no ideas, why it doesn't. Please, help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
    protected void initGameAndGUI(GameContainer arg0, StateBasedGame arg1) {

    LwjglInputSystem inputSystem = new LwjglInputSystem();

    try {
        inputSystem.startup();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }           
    PlainSlickInputSystem psis = new PlainSlickInputSystem();
    GameClient.app.getInput().addListener(psis);    

    prepareNifty(nifty, arg1);
    nifty = new Nifty(new LwjglRenderDevice(), new NullSoundDevice(),psis, new AccurateTimeProvider());
    NullSoundDevice(),psis, new AccurateTimeProvider());    
    initNifty(arg0, arg1, psis);    
    nifty.fromXml("...");

}
```

and ofcourse

```
nifty.update();
```

in your update method.

I was using Slick2d Nifty integration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call the [startup()](https://github.com/nifty-gui/nifty-gui/blob/1.4/nifty-renderer-lwjgl/src/main/java/de/lessvoid/nifty/renderer/lwjgl/input/LwjglInputSystem.java#L39) method at all on then LwjglInputSystem? We have example code available [here](https://github.com/nifty-gui/nifty-gui/blob/1.4/nifty-examples-lwjgl/src/main/java/de/lessvoid/nifty/examples/lwjgl/NiftyExampleLoaderLWJGL.java#L274) on how that is meant to be called. This is necessary to init the LwjglInputSystem properly.

However, why don't you use the ready made Slick2d integration classes we offer here: [Slick2d Nifty-GUI classes](https://github.com/nifty-gui/nifty-gui/tree/1.4/nifty-renderer-slick2d/src/main/java/de/lessvoid/nifty/slick2d)? They might be better suited to easily integrate Nifty GUI with Slick2d instead of relying on LWJGL directly.

Comment: Thanks, but your solution didn't work. Yep, i have tryed  Nifty + Slick 2d states, but they didn't help me. Thanks for you answer!